# Why does scipy.integrate.quad fail for this integral?

Tags: python, math, scipy, sympy

I am trying to compute the [Kullback Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) between two probability distributions. To do this I need to perform this integral.

[image]

Here is my simpified code which currently fails:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return sum([ps[idx]*lambdas[idx]*np.exp(- lambdas[idx] * x) for idx in range(len(ps))])
def g(x):
    return scipy.stats.weibull_min.pdf(x, c=c)
c = 0.9
ps = [1]
lambdas = [1]
eps = 0.001  # weibull_min is only defined for x > 0
print(quad(lambda x: f(x) * np.log(f(x) / g(x)), eps, np.inf)) # Output should be greater than 0
```

This gives:

```
(nan, nan)
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:11: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  # This is added back by InteractiveShellApp.init_path()
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:11: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  # This is added back by InteractiveShellApp.init_path()
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:11: IntegrationWarning: The occurrence of roundoff error is detected, which prevents 
  the requested tolerance from being achieved.  The error may be 
  underestimated.
  # This is added back by InteractiveShellApp.init_path()
```

Why doesn't it work and how can I get it to work?

Comment: According to a quick test I did, `f(x)`, `g(x)`, and `f(x)/g(x)` tend towards zero at infinity. This would explain the `log` error.

Comment: Hmm... That seems to suggest you can't compure KL divergence numerically for any of a huge class of probability distributions.

Comment: Maybe you need a transformation of some kind or a different quadrature.  Perhaps a log-quadrature can better handle that singularity.

Comment: You should consider another technique to compute the integral. For example, the division can be split in two (`log(f(x))-log(g(x))`), and both functions contains exponential functions that can be simplified with the log. You should obtain a simpler, well-behaved integration.

Comment: Thank you. Any help would be very much appreciate.

Comment: Or since the factor `f(x)` in front of the log tends towards zero quite fast, you don't have to integrate to infinity to have a good numerical approximation. Cut it at 20 for example. I just did it and got the correct answer with high precision (according to the analytic integral given by Mathematica)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `f(x)/g(x)` tends towards zero and can cause numerical errors. Since the whole integrand tends towards zero quite fast, you can simply integrate over a finite range (say [0.001, 20]) and still get a precise estimation of the integral:

```
from scipy.stats import weibull_min
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np

c = 0.9
ps = [1]
lambdas = [1]
def f(x):
    return sum([ps[idx]*lambdas[idx]*np.exp(- lambdas[idx] * x) for idx in range(len(ps))])
def g(x):
    return scipy.stats.weibull_min.pdf(x, c=c)
print(scipy.integrate.quad(lambda x: f(x) * np.log(f(x) / g(x)), 0.001, 30))
```

I did not do a numerical analysis of the precision, but according to the comparison with the result from Mathematica, it is precise to the 9th decimal. Here is the test code in Mathematica (simplified for your parameters):

```
f[x_] := Exp[-x];
c = 0.9;
g[x_] := c*x^(c - 1)*Exp[-x^c];
SetPrecision[Integrate[f[x]*Log[f[x]/g[x]], {x, 0.001, \[Infinity]}],20]
```

Mathematica result: 0.010089328699390866240
Scipy result: 0.01008932870010536

Comment: What did you do in mathematica exactly?

Comment: @Anush I edited my answer to include the code and results from Mathematica

Comment: Very interesting that mathematica can cope where quad can't. I wonder how it does it and if there is python equivalent.

Comment: Maybe sympy could do it?

Comment: @Anush I guess that Mathematica can store floating point values with arbitrary precision and that it has a better stopping criterion for integration, but I don't know that they do differently. In any case, I would personnally not bother with trying to gain extra precision with sympy because the formula you have might be already precise enough for your application. It all depends on your needs.

Comment: The reason I am interested is that my lambdas and ps arrays will in general be longer and have different values in them.

Comment: @Anush I see. I would still go for the numerical integration, but with some kind of safeguards for division by zero and small values in the log function. For example, your function could be `lambda x: 0 if f(x) < 1e-8 else f(x) * np.log(f(x) / g(x))`, and using the `np.inf` upperbound. I just tested and it works. Just make sure that it can work with different parameters.